# How to start neo4j server (desktop edition) using python and without launching the desktop application?

Tags: python, neo4j

I'm using neo4j Desktop Edition v4.4 & I've already integrated it with python (3.10) to create nodes and relationships.. this part is working fine, but I need to interact with neo4j server and database offline (without launching the desktop server). Would you please support?

Comment: Neo4j Desktop is just one way to provision Neo4j servers.
You can use [Docker](https://neo4j.com/developer/docker/), [Helm charts](https://neo4j.com/labs/neo4j-helm/1.0.0/) and many other ways to set up a server.

Comment: If your application needs to also work when your Neo4j server is offline, just make sure to call `verifyConnectivity` first on the driver instance and handle the connectivity error.

Comment: @fbiville Thank you..This is a good idea. I'm actually new to neo4j.  If possible, Can you guide me to a python code snippet to start the neo4j server? I'd appreciate that.

Comment: How about os.command('neo4j start')?

Comment: @cuneyttyler  Thank you. I installed neo4j Docker. Much more efficient and easier than integrating with the Desktop app.